# Maximal submodule not containing an element

Tags: modules, noncommutative-rings

[Title was: Let $M$ be a module, $N$ a submodule in $M$, conditions on $x$ and $M$ ($N\leq M$ or existence of $K\leq M$ maximal $x\not \in K N\leq K$) such that $Rx+N=M$]

Let $M$ be a left $R$ module.If $N\leq M$ with $Rx+N=M$  then either
$N=M$ or there exists a maximal submodule $K$ of $M$ with $N\leq K$ and $x\not \in K$.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not completely clear to me but I think the following statement could solve your problem:

LEMMA. Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ a left $R$-module, $N\leq M$ and $x\in M$ such that $N+Rx=M$ and $x\notin N$. Then, there is a submodule $K$ of $M$ which is maximal w.r.t. the properties of containing $N$ and not containing $x$.

PROOF. Consider the poset (with the partial order given by inclusion) $\mathcal F=\{X\leq M: N\leq X, x\notin X\}$. This poset is not empty as it contains $N$. Given a chain $X_1\leq X_2\leq \ldots\leq X_\alpha\leq \ldots$ of elements in $\mathcal F$, notice that $\bigcup X_\alpha$ belongs to $\mathcal F$. To conclude, apply Zorn's Lemma.\\\